# Is it possible to create mock api on this cypress to prevent the actual api call

Tags: vue.js, cypress

We have an vue js application which contains the component, On this component, there is an api call to update database records. We are doing unit test for this component.

Is it possible to create mock api on this cypress to prevent the actual api call? So database will not be modified during the unit test and can keep actual data as it is on database.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock it indeed. For example this mocks a server and a specific API-call:

```js
  cy.server()
  cy.route('POST', '**/oauth/v2/token', 'fixture:/oauth/agent-token.json')
```

More information about route is available on the cypress site: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html

Comment: Keep in mind that currently only XHR is supported, thus Fetch/WebSocket/Beacon/... based APIs aren't mockable right now.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure every request is mocked, use the `force404` option with `cy.server`:

```js
 cy.server({force404: true})
    cy.route('**/user/jake', {user:{name:'Jake'})
    cy.visit('/')
    // your test code here
```

Then any XHR request to `/user/jake` will work, but `/user/jane` and `/login` for example, will `404`

Comment: Can we use `cy.route()` to test Single Sign On with microsoft account and then redirect to another url ? I am have tried with `cy.request()` and couldn't get through and redirected to another url.

Comment: I think that would qualify as it's own question